# Removing some parts of a data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, data-cleaning

Please how can I turn this data

```
₹8,36,874/yr
₹6,69,578/yr
₹9,44,110/yr
```

to integer with Pandas.
I want to work on this data but the comma,'₹',and '/yr' is making it add for me to analyze it, please can someone put me through on how I remove them

Comment: walk over the string in a list comprehension and skip all non digit characters and then `''.join(comprehension_result)`

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'col1': ['₹8,36,874/yr', '₹6,69,578/yr', '₹9,44,110/yr']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

df

```
    col1
0   ₹8,36,874/yr
1   ₹6,69,578/yr
2   ₹9,44,110/yr
```

**Code**

replace non-digit-char to '' by regex(func `str.replace`), and make result to int dtype.

```
df['col1'].str.replace('\D', '', regex=True).astype('int')
```

output:

```
0    836874
1    669578
2    944110
Name: col1, dtype: int32
```